# No overload matches this call in middleware Next.js/Typescript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, middleware, next-auth

No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 4, '(args_0: GetServerSidePropsContext): Promise<Session | null>', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(req: NextAuthRequest) => Response | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetServerSidePropsContext'.
Overload 2 of 4, '(args_0: (req: NextAuthRequest) => void | Response | Promise<void | Response>): AppRouteHandlerFn', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(req: NextAuthRequest) => Response | null' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req: NextAuthRequest) => void | Response | Promise<void | Response>'.
Type 'Response | null' is not assignable to type 'void | Response | Promise<void | Response>'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'void | Response | Promise<void | Response>'.ts(2769)
(parameter) req: NextAuthRequest

i got this error under the this part : "(req) => {"

here is the full file :

```
import authConfig from "@/auth.config";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import {
  apiAuthPrefix,
  DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
  authRoutes,
  publicRoutes,
} from "@/routes";
export const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig);

export default auth((req) => {
  const { nextUrl } = req;
  const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth;
  const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix);
  const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
  const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);

  if (isApiAuthRoute) {
    return null;
  }
  if (isAuthRoute) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl));
    }
    return null;
  }
  if (!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL("/auth/login", nextUrl));
  }

  return null;
});

// Optionally, don't invoke Middleware on some paths
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

just return a native Response, or just do a simple return without the null

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).